# How to plot a histogram from a group?

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by, dataset

I am using R studio. What happens is that I have a dataset in which I have 1000k data. I have all columns called FINAL_CLASSIFICATION and AGE. In the FINAL_RANKING column there is data ranging from 1 to 7. In this column we say that those with 1, 2 or 3, are infected with SARS_COVID, while in those with 4, 5,6 and 7 are those who are healthy. I need to make a histogram of the ages of those who are infected and for this I understand that I must make a group to see the ages that coincide with 1, 2 and 3 of the column CLASIFICACION_FINAL and those ages will be of the infected people and, from there I need to make the histogram but I do not find the way to create the group or to obtain this.

Could you help me?

I have the following code

```
#1) 
# import the data into R
# RECOMMENDATION: use read_csv

covid_dataset <- read_csv("Desktop/Course in R/Examples/covid_dataset.csv")
View(covid_dataset)


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


#2) Extract a random sample of 100k records and assign it into a new variable. From now on work with this dataset
# HINT: use dplyr's sample_n function

sample <- sample_n(covid_dataset, 100000)

# With the function sample_n what we get is a syntax sample_n(x,n) where we have that
#x will be our dataset from where we want to extract the sample and n is the sample size
#that we want

nrow(sample)

#with this function we can corroborate that we have extracted a 100K sample.


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


#3)Make a statistical summary of the dataset and also show the data types by column.

summary(sample)

#The summary function is the one that gives us the summary statistics. 

map(sample, class)

#The map() function gives us the data type by columns and we can see that there are
#more numeric data type.

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#4)Filter the rows that are positive for SARS-COVID and calculate the number of records.
## Positive cases are those that in the FINAL_CLASSIFICATION column have 1, 2 or 3.


## To filter the rows, we will make use of the PIPE operator and the select function of dplyr.
#This will help us to select the column and to be able to filter the rows where
#the FINAL_CLASSIFICATION column is 1, 2 or 3, i.e. SARS-COVID positive results.



sample %>% select(FINAL_CLASSIFICATION) %>% filter(FINAL_CLASSIFICATION == 1) 

# Here I filter the rows for which the column FINAL_CLASSIFICATION has a 1

sample %>% select(FINAL_CLASSIFICATION) %>% filter(FINAL_CLASSIFICATION == 2)

# Here I filter the rows for which the column FINAL_CLASSIFICATION has a 2

sample %>% select(FINAL_CLASSIFICATION) %>% filter(FINAL_CLASSIFICATION == 3)

# Here I filter the rows for which the column FINAL_CLASSIFICATION has a 3



# I do them separately to have a better view of the records.




#Now if we want to get them all together we simply do the following

sample %>% select(FINAL_CLASSIFICATION) %>% filter(FINAL_CLASSIFICATION <= 3)

#This gives us the rows less than or equal to 3, which is the same as giving us the rows in which the
#Rows where the FINAL_RANKING column has 1, 2 or 3.


#Now, if we want the number of records, doing it separately, we simply add
#another PIPE operator in which we will add the nrow() function to give me the number of #rows for each record.
#rows for each record.

sample %>% select(FINAL_CLASSIFICATION) %>% filter(FINAL_CLASSIFICATION == 1) %>% nrow()

#gives us a result of 1471

sample %>% select(FINAL_CLASSIFICATION) %>% filter(FINAL_CLASSIFICATION == 2) %>% nrow()

#gives us a result of 46

sample %>% select(FINAL_CLASSIFICATION) %>% filter(FINAL_CLASSIFICATION == 3) %>% nrow()

#Gives us a result of 37703


#If we add the 3 results, we have that the total number of records is

1471+46+37703

#Which gives us 39220


#But it can be simplified by doing it in a straightforward way as follows 

sample %>% select(FINAL_CLASSIFICATION) %>% filter(FINAL_CLASSIFICATION <= 3) %>% nrow()

#And we notice that we get the same result as the previous code. 

#In conclusion, we have a total of 39220 positive SARS-COVID cases.
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


#5)Count the number of null records per column (HINT: Use sapply or map, and is.na)


apply(sample, MARGIN = 2, function(x)sum(is.na(x))))

#This shows us the number of NA's per column. We notice that the only column
#that has NA's is the DATE_DEF with a total of 95044, this tells us that out of the
#100K data, only approximately 5k data are known for DATE_DEF.



#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#6)
##a)Calculate the mean age of covid infectees.
##b)Make a histogram of the ages of the infected persons. 
##c)Make a density plot of the ages of the infected persons


sample %>% group_by(FINAL_CLASSIFICATION
  group_by(FINAL_CLASSIFICATION <= 3 ) %>% %>%
  summarise(average = mean(AGE))


#Then the total average number of infected is 43.9


#Now we make a histogram of the ages of the infected persons

sample %>% group_by(FINAL_CLASSIFICATION <=3, AGE) %>% summarise(count = n())
```

It is in the last part where I have doubts. I want to find the average of the ages of the infected people, I used the code that I put there using group_by but I don't know if that is correct. And my doubts are already with the other two questions in #6, where I want to know about the histograms and how to plot them.

Comment: Could you provide your data using `dput()` ? I'm confused what you exactly want. You want to plot a histogram of ages of the infected people?

Comment: @YHJang In this link, you can download the dataset that I am using http://datosabiertos.salud.gob.mx/gobmx/salud/datos_abiertos/datos_abiertos_covid19.zip,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I gathered is that you wish to 1. create a variable 'FINAL_CLASSIFICATION' based on values of 'FINAL_RANKING,' 2. summarize the average age of groups in FINAL_CLASSIFICATION, and 3. create a histogram of the positive cases in FINAL_CLASSIFICATION

I created a random sample of 100 cases with random assumptions of AGE and FINAL_RANKING

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

sample <- tibble(FINAL_RANKING = sample(1:7, 100, replace = T), AGE = sample(10:100, 100, replace = T) ) 

sample <- sample %>% 
    mutate(
        FINAL_CLASSIFICATION = case_when(
            FINAL_RANKING %in% 1:3 ~ "SARS_COVID_POSITIVE", 
            FINAL_RANKING %in% 4:7 ~ "SARS_COVID_NEGATIVE")
        ) 
sample %>% 
    group_by(FINAL_CLASSIFICATION) %>% 
    summarize(average_age = mean(AGE))

sample %>% 
    filter(FINAL_CLASSIFICATION == "SARS_COVID_POSITIVE") %>% 
    ggplot(., aes(x = AGE)) + 
    geom_histogram()
```

Gives summary output:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  FINAL_CLASSIFICATION average_age
  <chr>                      <dbl>
1 SARS_COVID_NEGATIVE         51.8
2 SARS_COVID_POSITIVE         58.6
```

and plot:

[image: histogram_of_count_of_ages_of_positive_cases]

As noted in output, you should adjust bins

Comment: Sizdek Yes, that is correct. I want to find the average number of infected people and I also want to plot both a histogram and a density curve for the ages of infected people. I understand your code and it is fine, but I can't find how I can use my data. I see that you apparently used ages ranging from 10 to 100 and used 100 random data for the ages, but how would I do it by taking my data from my AGE and FINAL_CLASSIFICATION column, but what you did is exactly what I want.

Comment: If you want histogam + density plot, change geom_histogram() -> geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..)) + geom_density(). To apply to your data, just substitute your dataframe name for 'sample' in my code.

Comment: There, I have succeeded in doing it. I thank you very much for helping me, I struggled a lot to solve that, thank you very much. One more doubt, how would the positive cases be grouped by states? In this case I have 32 states and I would like to group the positive cases by state. I know I can use group_by but I'm a bit confused about how to use it.

Comment: Great, glad it helped! The appropriate course at this point would be to accept the answer, so it will be helpful to others, as well. To your new question, apply the techniques above to this new situation 1. You want positive cases so filter -> filter(FINAL_CLASSIFICATION == "SARS_COVID_POSITIVE") %>%, 2. you want to group by state, so group_by(STATE) %>%

Comment: I am a bit confused, I understand that the filter is to filter my positive cases and the group_by is to group with the variable I want. I already filtered my positive cases with the filter and I get this filter but for all the columns. Now I want to use group_by to group by state, but I don't know how to put my filter to the group_by.

Comment: I would like to see the total number of infected for state 1, the total number of infected for state 2, the total number of infected for state 3 and so on. But in the filter it shows me that there are 39,220 cases, which is indeed the total number of infections, but it shows me one by one the total number of cases.

Comment: I managed to group it and get the totals, thank you very much. It helped me with the filter, and with the group_by I just managed to get the grouping by state, thank you very much.